# Can't access NodeJS api from Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have trouble trying to get to my NodeJs server from my angular app. Here's my router:

```
app.get('/new12345',function(req,res){
    console.log("Http Get Recently Gone from /new12345");
    var results = userData;
    res.send(results);
});
```

Here where I try getting to my api.

```
this.http.get('/new12345').subscribe(data => {
  this.resultInArray = data['results'];
}
```

I am getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9E8.png) though:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new12345'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify your api base url. You are currently getting to your angular app (hence the angular router error you are getting).

For example, that might look like this:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/new12345').subscribe(data => {
    this.resultInArray = data['results'];
}
```

Comment: where (in node or angular) is need to specify base api... i am new in mea2n stack...

Comment: it's not work for me... because in console log didn't print anything in console like... "Http Get Recently Gone from /new12345" which i print to check my app is gone from "/new12345" node api...